# Translating characters in a string to multiple characters using Python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings with prefix characters representing the multiplying factor for the number. So if I have data like:

```
data = ['101n', '100m', '100.100f']
```

I want to use the dictionary

```
prefix_dict = {'y': 'e-24', 'z': 'e-21', 'a': 'e-18', 'f': 'e-15', 'p': 'e-12',
               'n': 'e-9', 'u': 'e-6', 'm': 'e-3', 'c': 'e-2', 'd': 'e-1',
               'da': 'e1', 'h': 'e2', 'k': 'e3', 'M': 'e6', 'G': 'e9',
               'T': 'e12', 'P': 'e15', 'E': 'e18', 'Z': 'e21', 'Y': 'e24'}
```

To insert their corresponding strings. When I look at the other questions similar to mine there is one character being translated into another character. Is there a way to use the translate function to translate one character into multiple characters or should I be approaching this differently?

Comment: give an example of the output you expect

Comment: Sorry, the output I expect is out = ['101e-9', '100e-3', '100.100e-15']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex for this, this works for `'da'` as well:

```
>>> data = ['101n', '100m', '100.100f', '1d', '1da']
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+)$')
>>> for d in data:
    print r.sub(lambda m: prefix_dict.get(m.group(1), m.group(1)), d)
...     
101e-9
100e-3
100.100e-15
1e-1
1e1
```

And a non-regex version using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> def find_suffix(s):
    return ''.join(takewhile(str.isalpha, s[::-1]))[::-1]
... 
>>> for d in data:
    sfx = find_suffix(d)
    print (d.replace(sfx, prefix_dict.get(sfx, sfx)))
...     
101e-9
100e-3
100.100e-15
1e-1
1e1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for i, entry in enumerate(data):
    for key, value in sorted(prefix_dict.items(), 
                             key = lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True):     
# need to sort the dictionary so that 'da' always comes before 'a'
        if key in entry:
            data[i] = entry.replace(key, value)
print(data)
```

This works for arbitrary combinations in the dictionary and the data. If the dictionary key is always only 1 string long, you have lots of other solutions posted here.

Comment: does not change any values in the list

Answer (score 0):

```
 import re

data = ['101da', '100m', '100.100f']

prefix_dict = {'y': 'e-24', 'z': 'e-21', 'a': 'e-18', 'f': 'e-15', 'p': 'e-12',
               'n': 'e-9', 'u': 'e-6', 'm': 'e-3', 'c': 'e-2', 'd': 'e-1',
               'da': 'e1', 'h': 'e2', 'k': 'e3', 'M': 'e6', 'G': 'e9',
               'T': 'e12', 'P': 'e15', 'E': 'e18', 'Z': 'e21', 'Y': 'e24'}
comp = re.compile(r"[^\[A-Za-z]")
for ind,d in enumerate(data):
    pre = re.sub(comp,"",d)
    data[ind] = d.replace(pre,prefix_dict.get(pre))
print data
['101e1', '100e-3', '100.100e-15']
```

You can use `pre = [x for x in d if x.isalpha()][0]` instead of using re

Comment: does this work for keys that are not just one character?

Comment: so you have keys that are more than one character?

Comment: look in the dictionary above, example: 'da'

Comment: There's one I included for completeness that's two characters, but for the data I'm looking at I can drop this from the dictionary.